# pyqt5 вывод текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как вывести текст который написан в `QLineEdit` в консоль или в sqlite

Comment: Возможно `.text()`

Comment: @diraria а в `QTextEdit` ?

Comment: Возможно `.plainText`

Comment: @diraria пишет `'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'PlainText'`

Comment: Тогда, возможно `.toPlainText()`

Comment: @diraria большое спасибо часа 2 искал информацию)

Comment: Написал, как находил эти методы, может быть это будет полезным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) — метод [`.text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)
- [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) — методы [`.toPlainText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) и [`.toHtml()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop)
- [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) — метод [`.toPlainText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#toPlainText)

В будущем, чтобы найти имя метода, можно воспользоваться C++ документацией по Qt (python документацию либо я не нашёл, либо она не очень понятная):

- Заходим на [сайт C++ документации по Qt](http://doc.qt.io/)
- Вводим в поле поиска интересующий класс (например, `QLineEdit`)
- Скорее всего, [первой ссылкой](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=qlineedit) будет [документация по этому классу](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)
- Просматриваем разделы `Properties` и `Public Functions`
- Ищем имя какого-нибудь метода, похожее на то что нам нужно

Comment: Стоит явно упомянуть что это C++ документация. Хотя как правило легко и по C++ объявлению метода догадаться как на Питоне его вызвать.

Comment: Есть еще `QPlainTextEdit`, а у `QTextEdit` есть `toHtml()`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, обновил