# Передача значений spinBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qspinbox

Как будет выглядеть передача значений из `QSpinBox`, созданного `MainWindow` в *Qt Designer*, в переменную `r` объявленную в скрипте (модуле) Питон?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from MyMainWindow import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import strorint


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()
    
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Stop')
        self.ui.StartpushButton.clicked.connect(self.str)
        self.ui.StoppushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Stop)
        self.ui.StartpushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage(' запущен'))
        self.ui.StoppushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage(' остановлен'))
        
    def str(self):
       pass
        
    def Stop(self):
        pass
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [pyqt5 вывод текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718081/255866)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем значение с помощью QSpinBox.value().

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Main(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.spinBox = Qt.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(0 , 50)

        self.button = Qt.QPushButton("Value")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.getValue)

        self.getValueLabel = Qt.QLabel("Value'll be here.")

        # Building layout
        self.Layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.getValueLabel)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def getValue(self):
        self.value = self.spinBox.value()    # Value of Box
        # If we need to show value on screen
        self.getValueLabel.setText('Value : {0}'.format(self.value) )



# Running
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `QtWidgets` не нужен, если есть `Qt`, поэтому `QtWidgets.QSpinBox` -> `Qt.QSpinBox` :) нет смысла в лишнем коде :)

Comment: у меня уже есть готовый шаблон и модуль(скрипт) питона запускающий, я так понимаю примеры что привели вы и выше это создание спина! он уже есть в виджете вот его значение как передать в переменную?

Comment: value = [Qt.QSpinBox - имя переменной, которая ссылается на бокс, который у вас есть.].value().

Comment: а имя модуля питона (в котором переменная)называть(объявлять) не надо?

Comment: нет, можно так : `value = myBox.value()`, где myBox - объект класса `Qt.QComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

При помощи функции [`SpinBox.text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#text-prop) вы можете вывести значение из `SpinBox`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        push = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Вывести значение")
        push.clicked.connect(self.change)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.spin)
        layout.addWidget(push)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def change(self):
        self.r = int(self.spin.text())
        print(self.r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `text` не очень подходит т.к. включает в себя префиксы, постфиксы и т.п. А вот value подойдет: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#value-prop

Comment: r - это переменная в модуле питона?а где непосредственно передача значения в переменную?у меня уже есть готовый шаблон и модуль(скрипт) питона запускающий, я так понимаю примеры что привели вы и выше это создание спина! он уже есть в виджете вот его значение как передать в переменную?

Comment: @Venus `self.r = int(self.spin.text())` это и есть передача значение в переменную

Comment: @gil9red да согласен, но как так сказать к дополнению уже позже написанному ответу тоже подойдет) (так сказать вариант с костылями)

Comment: r я так понимаю переменная объявленная в модуле питона, а имя модуля не надо указывать?и почему текст если у него int передаётся?

Comment: @Venus зачем если это просто переменная которая хранит изначально тип `str` и [т.к. меня уже исправили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852099/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-spinbox/852121?noredirect=1#comment1372360_852121) и по сути это является костылем получения значения в `QSpinBox()`, лучше использовать вариант с `QSpinBox.value()` ответ на который описан выше

Comment: добавил self.r = int(self.spin.text()) вылезло такое ((  AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'spinBox'

Comment: @Venus ну наверное потому что вы вставляете данный фрагмент в свой код а в вашем коде нету такого атрибута. Для более понятного ответа на ваш вопрос вы бы хотя бы свои исходники выложили бы чтобы как то более понятно ответить на ваш вопрос.С тем учетом что исходя из предыдущего вашего вопроса вы делаете это через `Designer` (а это вы не уточняете), вам отвечают на ваш вопрос не используя его.

Comment: ну в дизайнере создал шаблон, потом файл main чтоб запускал окно(виджет) в нём спинбокс и вот его значение передать в переменную скрипта(модуля)питон

Comment: @Venus В прошлом вашем вопросе у вас был такой же случай и в данном вопросе можно использовать его тоже. Проще вам просто выложить код `designer`

Comment: в том примере текст был lineEdit, а тут уже спинбокс читал документацию они разные так я понял и значения по разно передают?

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз, когда значение изменяется, 
`QSpinBox` испускает сигналы `QSpinBox.valueChanged()`.

Текущее значение может быть выбрано с помощью `QSpinBox.value()` и 
установлено с помощью `QSpinBox.setValue()`.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.sb_font_size = Qt.QSpinBox()
        self.sb_font_size.setRange(1, 99)
        self.sb_font_size.setValue(12)                                   
        self.sb_font_size.valueChanged.connect(self.fontSizeChanged)

        self.sizeLabel = Qt.QLabel("Значениe из SpinBoxt: <b style='color: blue;'> 12 </b>")
        self.fontLabel = Qt.QLabel("Font of text: <b style='color: blue;'>Times New Roman</b>")

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.sizeLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.sb_font_size)

        central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        

    def fontSizeChanged(self, value):
        self.sizeLabel.setText("Значениe из SpinBoxt: <b style='color: blue;'> {} </b>".format(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    MainWin = MainWindow()
    MainWin.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня уже есть готовый шаблон и модуль(скрипт) питона запускающий, я так понимаю примеры что привели вы и выше это создание спина! он уже есть в виджете вот его значение как передать в переменную?