# Как передать значение переменной из окна MyWin2 в MyWin?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Не могу перенести значение переменной **`n`** из `MyWin2()` в `MyWin()`.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Graph22 import *
from Settings import *


class MyWin2(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.n)  # Начиная с этой части не понимаю, как лучше сделать

    def n(self):
        self.n = int(self.ui.lineEdit.toPlainText())


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, n)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.SetBut)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Chif)
        self.n = n  # Это тоже под сомнением

    def SetBut(self):
        self.mywin2 = MyWin2()
        self.mywin2.show()

    def Chif(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText("")

        eng = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
        ENG = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        RUS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
        nums = " 1234567890"
        s = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        # Где-то здесь должно быть значение n
        res = ''
        for i in s:
            try:
                res += rus[(rus.index(i) + n) % len(rus)]
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    res += eng[(eng.index(i) + n) % len(eng)]
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        res += RUS[(RUS.index(i) + n) % len(RUS)]
                    except ValueError:
                        try:
                            res += ENG[(ENG.index(i) + n) % len(ENG)]
                        except ValueError:
                            res += nums[(nums.index(i) + n) % len(nums)]
        kp = 'Result: "' + res + '"'

        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(kp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Settings.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(295, 232)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 20, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Цезарь"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Индексация"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Литорея"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "N="))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButtton"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ок"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Отмена"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Graph22.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(522, 340)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 261, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 100, 261, 71))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 272, 521, 21))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 170, 521, 101))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 521, 101))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 522, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зашифровать"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расшифровать"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройки"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройки"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: P.S последняя часть немного деформировалась, верный вариант:
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Вообще-то для манипуляции с целочисленными значениями лучше использовать `spinBox`. Вы намного увеличите шансы получить ответ, если опубликуете модули `Graph22` и `Settings`

Comment: @S.Nick, Сегодня, к сожалению, не смогу опубликовать данные модули, но вы бы не могли немного разъяснить ситуацию с spinBox?

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852099/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-spinbox

Comment: @S.Nick, добавил Graph22 и Settings, поможете?)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `self.mywin2.show()` использовать `self.mywin2.exec()` а ниже добавьте `print(self.mywin2.n)` или напрямую к виджету `print(self.mywin2.ui.lineEdit.toPlainText())`. Кст, у `QLineEdit` нет `toPlainText`, а значит у вас приложение падает. Вызывайте `text()` -> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного прокомментировал ваш код. Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5    import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Graph22  import Ui_MainWindow
from Settings import Ui_Dialog


class MyWin2(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
#        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.n)  # Начиная с этой части не понимаю, как лучше сделать
        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.nFunc)
        self.n = 0

    def nFunc(self):
#        self.n = int(self.ui.lineEdit.toPlainText())
        self.n = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        print("self.n-", self.n)

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, n)      # n - ???
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.SetBut)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Chif)
        self.n = 0                     # ??? Это тоже под сомнением

    def SetBut(self):
        self.mywin2 = MyWin2()
        self.mywin2.show()
### +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        self.mywin2.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okClicked)
        self.mywin2.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.mywin2.hide)

    def okClicked(self):        
        self.n = self.mywin2.n
        print("def okClicked->", self.n)
        self.mywin2.hide()
### ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       


    def Chif(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText("")

        eng = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
        ENG = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        RUS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
        nums = " 1234567890"
        s = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()

        # Где-то здесь должно быть значение n
        n = self.n  # ???

        res = ''
        print("s->", s)  ####
        for i in s:
            if i in rus:
                res += rus[(rus.index(i) + n) % len(rus)]
            elif i in eng:
                res += eng[(eng.index(i) + n) % len(eng)]
            elif i in RUS:    
                res += RUS[(RUS.index(i) + n) % len(RUS)]
            elif i in ENG:    
                res += ENG[(ENG.index(i) + n) % len(ENG)]
            elif i in nums:    
                res += nums[(nums.index(i) + n) % len(nums)]
            else:
# подумайте надо ли вам сделать что-то типа  symbol = ",./!?...#-"
                print("Символ `{}` не шифруется?".format(i))
                res += i

            """  Старайтесь не использовать конструкцию `try - except` в PyQt
            try:
                res += rus[(rus.index(i) + n) % len(rus)]
                print("res rus-", res, rus.index(i), len(rus))
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    res += eng[(eng.index(i) + n) % len(eng)]
                    print("res eng-", res, eng.index(i), len(eng))
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        res += RUS[(RUS.index(i) + n) % len(RUS)]
                    except ValueError:
                        try:
                            res += ENG[(ENG.index(i) + n) % len(ENG)]
                        except ValueError:
                            res += nums[(nums.index(i) + n) % len(nums)]
            """

        kp = 'Result: "' + res + '"'

        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(kp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]